# iterating through an array of objects in an object while also grabbing an outer value

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I've been stuck on something simple for a little bit. I have the following response JSON:

```
{
    "terminalName": "Montreal",
    "shipThruLocationCodes":[
        {
            "shipThruLocationId": 112,
            "shipThruLocationCode": "B84"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a select where I need to display `terminalName (shipThruLocationCode)` for each item in the shipThruLocationCodes array, there will only be one terminalName.  The data is stored in an array in the controller called `$scope.shipThrus`.  This is what I tried in my ng-repeat but it did not work:

`data-ng-options="shipThru.terminalName for shipThru in shipThrus, item.shipThruLocationCode for item in shipThru.shipThruLocationCodes"`

I think my idea is correct, but the comma (since I'm trying to display two values) is throwing an error.

So to summarize, the select should show the following for each item
`"terminal Name" (shipThruLocationCode)`

There will be only one terminal name and can be multiple location codes in the shipThrulocationCodes array.

Comment: could you please be more specific as in what should be the options in your `select` ?

Comment: Sure.  editing the question

Comment: Why the function creation is here? @JBNizet

Comment: Use a function creating all the pairs of terminalName-shipThruLocationCode in your controller. Iterate on the result of that function in your view: `ng-options="pair.terminalName + ' (' + pair.shipThruLocationCode + ')' for pair in pairs"`

Comment: @SaadShahd it's a mistake on my part: calloing the function every time will make it a problem to select anything. I've changed my comment, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function to generate the options. Here's a Plunker to show you an example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/hxlowXWCS6BWh6gGfMMl?p=preview

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="main.selectedOption" ng-options="option.name for option in main.options"></select>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('angularApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.terminals = [
    {
      "terminalName": "Montreal",
      "shipThruLocationCodes":[
          {
            "shipThruLocationId": 112,
            "shipThruLocationCode": "B84"
          }
      ]
    },
    {
      "terminalName": "Somewhere else",
      "shipThruLocationCodes":[
          {
            "shipThruLocationId": 113,
            "shipThruLocationCode": "B9999"
          }
      ]
    }
  ];

  vm.options = [];

  generateOptions();

  function generateOptions() {
    for(var i = 0; i < vm.terminals.length; i++) {
      var selectOption = {
        name: vm.terminals[i].terminalName + " (" + vm.terminals[i].shipThruLocationCodes[0].shipThruLocationCode + ")"
      };
      vm.options.push(selectOption);
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: great! just add `vm.selectedOption = vm.options[0];` after `generateOptions();` in `js` that'll get rid of the blank option in `select`

Comment: yeah that's great, much better to pre process instead of complex ng-repeat statements that aren't readable..will accept this after trying it out

Answer (score 0):

Check Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Vs2mC9zt3HmO9KGMzV6D?p=preview

If you have the list as:

```
$scope.shipThrus = [{
  terminalName: "Montreal",
  shipThruLocationCodes: [{
    shipThruLocationId: 112,
    shipThruLocationCode: "B84"
  }, {
    shipThruLocationId: 112,
    shipThruLocationCode: "B89"
  }]
}];
```

Just create this function:

```
function getLocationCodes(shipThru) {
  return shipThru.shipThruLocationCodes.map(function(locationCode) {
    return locationCode.shipThruLocationCode;
  }).join(', ');
};
```

Which will parse the `locationCodes` to `B84, B89`.

Then parse the `shipThrus`:

```
$scope.shipThrus.forEach(function(shipThru) {
  shipThru.label = shipThru.terminalName + ' (' + getLocationCodes(shipThru) + ')';
});
```

Now you can create the select element with the ng-options attribute as:

```
ng-options="shipThru.shipThruLocationCodes as shipThru.label for shipThru in shipThrus"
```